# how to solve "could not access file '$libdir/librouting'" problem in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: pgrouting

I am trying to install pgrouting in my ubuntu 12.04 machine using the instructions of this [link](http://pgrouting.org/docs/1.x/install.html). However, when I try to execute the following command based on step 3, it generates some error.

command

> > > psql -U postgres -f /media/resource/pgrouting/pgrouting/core/sql/routing_core.sql routing

Output:

> > > psql:routing_core.sql:21: ERROR:  type "path_result" already exists
> > >
> > > psql:routing_core.sql:22: ERROR:  type "vertex_result" already exists
> > >
> > > psql:routing_core.sql:32: ERROR:  could not access file 
> > >       "$libdir/librouting": No such file or directory
> > >
> > > psql:routing_core.sql:43: ERROR:  could not access file "$libdir/librouting": No such file or directory
> > >
> > > psql:routing_core.sql:53: ERROR:  could not access file "$libdir/librouting": No such file or directory
> > >
> > > CREATE FUNCTION

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

In case you don't need to make changes to the pgRouting source and compile yourself, why don't you use the Ubuntu packages?
See: http://workshop.pgrouting.org/chapters/installation.html

Otherwise the errors above might occur because your build failed. Have you checked, that there was no build error?

Comment: I have changed '$libdir/librouting' to hard coded path and its working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and used the same solution. For completeness' sake I have included the fix I made to the routing_core.sql file in Ubuntu 12.10/Linux Mint 14.  Below is an exceprt from the file showing the three changes I made replacing '$libdir/librouting' with '/usr/lib/postgresql/9.1/lib/librouting.so':

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION shortest_path(sql text, source_id integer, 
    target_id integer, directed boolean, has_reverse_cost boolean)
    RETURNS SETOF path_result
    AS '/usr/lib/postgresql/9.1/lib/librouting.so'
    LANGUAGE C IMMUTABLE STRICT;

-----------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Core function for shortest_path_astar computation
-- Simillar to shortest_path in usage but uses the A* algorithm
-- instead of Dijkstra's.
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION shortest_path_astar(sql text, source_id integer, 
        target_id integer,directed boolean, has_reverse_cost boolean)
         RETURNS SETOF path_result
         AS '/usr/lib/postgresql/9.1/lib/librouting.so'
         LANGUAGE C IMMUTABLE STRICT; 

-----------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Core function for shortest_path_astar computation
-- Simillar to shortest_path in usage but uses the Shooting* algorithm
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION shortest_path_shooting_star(sql text, source_id integer, 
        target_id integer,directed boolean, has_reverse_cost boolean)
         RETURNS SETOF path_result
         AS '/usr/lib/postgresql/9.1/lib/librouting.so'
         LANGUAGE C IMMUTABLE STRICT;
```